# How to store and easily reference numerous speed data points on a PIC microprocessor to accurately manage speed changes

Tags: c, embedded, storage, velocity, pic

Looking for advice and pointers on a problem that I have with a PIC microcontroller project.

A board will act as a control for a moving vehicle, using PWM. Controlling the motors is fine, no issues.  But I am looking for the acceleration and deceleration to be realistic.  Therefore I have mapped out some graphs for both showing the acceleration and deceleration curves (velocity time graph).

My problem is how to transfer these from graph paper into a suitable storage format that the PIC can easily and quickly read, and refer to.  So for example when accelerating from the start it can map what it is doing with the motor to the appropriate graph, depending on the target speed.  There are different graphs for different target speeds, and different trailing weights.

Obviously the higher the resolution of the data (ie more data points per graph = higher resolution) the more accurate, but also the more data points to be stored and referred to.  Some of these data points could be interpolated (calculated using the next and previous) rather than having to be specifically stored, but I have yet to establish if (as I suspect) that is just adding extra and unnecessary work onto the PIC microcontroller.

I have searched the web for storing speed curves, processing acceleration graphs etc, but not come up with anything useful.  Can anyone offer any pointers, thoughts, experience, of a suitable data store.  Obviously, being a PIC things like MongoDB and MySQL are out, it needs to be a flat data system that somehow can be reference, but I cannot be the first to look to do this.

Comment: Slope = rise / run... accel = delta velocity / delta time... Is that hard?

Comment: What model of PIC we are talking about here? How big your data would be?

Comment: @Fe203 Yes it is ... if your trying to get a model vehicle to react like a real vehicle would accelerating from 0 to 60 (on what ever speed range, mph or kph) with 50 tonnes of load behind, the graph would not be a straight line. It is a slow acceleration, then at a specific point, the acceleration decreases while still trying to reach the top speed.  Hence realistic representation cannot be a straight line graph, which is easily modelled.  Thats my issue.

Comment: @Kozmotronik The model PIC can vary, I am looking at an 18F66K80 - but if that needed to change it could.  The data all depends on the resolution, at base minimum it could be 10 entries per target speed, each giving an acceleration rate at 1/10th intervals between 0 and the target speed.  Alternatively it might be 30 entries at 1/30th intervals to give more precise details.  That decision could depend on the method of storage and the available storage space on the PIC.

Answer (score 1):

What the MCU needs to know is the duty cycle it should give out at a certain point in time. So if we assume 16 bit PWM the data could look like this:

```
static const uint16_t duty_cycle[n] = 
{
  0,
  1,
  3
  ...
};
```

A plain array stored in flash, where `n` is the number of time cycles you need to output the curve. For example if you need the acceleration to happen over the time of 1000ms and  you update the PWM every 10ms, then `n` would be 1000/10 = 100. And each time the 10ms update occurs, you increase the index of the array, for example:

```
void some_timer_isr (void)
{
  static int i=0;
  uint16_t update = duty_cycle[i];
  PWM_REGISTER = update;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that.  Interesting approach that I hadn't considered, but is obvious really.  That also puts the the resolution of the data into perspective (the number of steps).  Food for fought there, thank you.

Comment: @TIWDEV This is typically how you model any non-linear curve in any embedded system, at least while a PWM is involved as output.